# Exception with Excel SaveCopyAs() method

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, excel-addins

I have generated a excel report using excel-addins in vs2010 and it saved to desktop. After that I reopened  the same file and changed it's data. When I tried to save back with same file name Exception occurs.

***Code:-**
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);**

**Exception**:-
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\112\Desktop\111.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:
• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.*

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that your file isn't being used by something else.

You are almost certainly hitting a file access exception, probably because the document you are attempting to write is already open in another program.

I'm guessing that program is Microsoft Excel.

Close the document in Excel and re-run your test.